# Upgrading to Tridion 2013 with active items in workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow

What is the best method for upgrading from Tridion 2011 to Tridion 2013 with items in workflow? If possible, I would like to not have to install the legacy packs or release the current workflow items. Any ideas?

Comment: And what problem have you met?
Probably you need Legacy pack. In 2011 there was only VB ScriptType (default) and legacy workflow service for executing activities. In 2013 new Workflow Service was created. He can execute old VB-script activities, but for this VBScriptExecutor component must be installed (if I am not mistaken - it is part of the legacy pack).
So if you had automated activities, you need Legacy pack.
Also if you don't want to change your processDefinitions (scriptType ->csharp and rewrite all code) you need legacy pack.
So why you don't want to install legacy pack ?

Comment: We have not met a problem yet. Hoping to avoid problems by figuring out the best method to handle workflow after upgrading from 2011 to 2013. Vbscript has been deprecated and if I am not mistaken will be removed in Tridion 2015. We don't want to have to support vbscript and with the legacy pack installed, wont that give users the ability to continue creating templates with vbscript? When we upgrade from 2011 to 2013, there will still be many jobs in workflow. I guess we could install the legacy packs, wait for all legacy workflow items to finish and then uninstall the legacy pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading from Tridion 2011 to Tridion 2013 SP1, we found that even without installing the legacy pack that the items in workflow prior to the upgrade can still be finished. If you elect to pull your items out of workflow to put them in the new 2013 workflow, you can simply "Force Finish Process." When you access one of these 2011 workflow items, you will get an alert about VBScript not being found.

[image: Tridion 2013 Workflow error]